# Azure Mobile Services push notifications channel creation fails after adding Private Networks capability in Windows 8 XAML store app

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, azure-mobile-services

Azure Mobile Services push notifications have been working in my Windows 8 XAML Store app until I needed to access local network resources and had to add the Private Networks (Client & Server) capability.  Now the application generates the error below when I try to acquire the push channel

```
  CurrentChannel =
                await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

            CurrentChannel.PushNotificationReceived += CurrentChannel_PushNotificationReceived;
```

A notification channel request for the provided application identifier is in progress. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x803E0103)

Any idea why I can't acquire the push channel with the Private Networks capability enabled?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Your firewall may be blocking it because it now requests those privileges. Make sure there is an exception for your app.

Comment: Thanks Nate for the comment. I'm not sure why but rebooting fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted my computer and I can no longer reproduce the issue. I waited a few days to answer to make sure it didn't come back but it still working.  So rebooting seemed to fix it.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I had to close and open the app 2 times