# UWP - Create push notification channel error

Tags: push-notification, uwp, wns

I have a strange issue for creating a push notification channel uri.
When I try to execute the following code:

```
receivedChannel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
```

I catch an exception with the following message:

> A notification channel request for the provided application identifier is in progress. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x803E0103)

(nothing special in the call stack)

The problem appeared suddenly while it worked fine.
I tried to restart my phone without success.

Note: I have this issue only on my development mobile. It works fine on others mobiles.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? It's hard to say without more data. A reboot may helps like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871708/azure-mobile-services-push-notifications-channel-creation-fails-after-adding-pri). Besides, you can try to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see where the communication is getting bogged down.

Comment: Try close-opening the app 2 times. 1st time it stopped at splash screen. 2nd time thrown this exception. 3rd time launched perfectly. My release builds are working fine on fresh install itself. So didn't gave much thought about this.

Comment: This problem still exists. I found exactly same error while creating push notification channel. Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's properbly not relevant any more, but I had a support call earlier this year with Microsoft. This kind of error message is actually due to an error in the whole push notification framework. The problem has been resolved in the Fall Creator's update released on October 17th, 2017. As a matter of fact I have not encountered the error since then on any of the ~500 devices in my domain.

So, error resolution: Update your device. Hope that helps.